# .Net programs are compiled to DLL or EXE file types called "assemblies." Do assemblies contain machine-executable code

Tags: .net

.Net programs are compiled to DLL or EXE file types called "assemblies." Do assemblies contain machine-executable code

Comment: They do actually, at least 5 bytes of it.  More if it is a mixed-mode assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they contain MSIL (*).  Google for it, or read the [overview in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3677y81.aspx).

(*) Among other things, such as a manifest, Type metadata and resources.  And the resources can contain any binary data, including machine-executable code.  It's unusual, but there do exist assemblies that extract and run a non-managed DLL, which contains machine-executable code, from a resource embedded in an assembly.

Answer (score 1):

The Dll and Exe actually contain a code called MSIL (Microsoft Intermediate Language) which if you examine with ILDASM (Intermediate Language Disassembler) resembles an hybrid of Assembler and "C". These assemblies are compiled at run time to actual machine code using the "JIT" or Just In Time compiler.

There is a utility (NGEN) which can precompile the IL to Native Machine Code.

A more complete version of this can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Cheers,

CEC

Answer (score 0):

Assemblies are containers for .NET managed code compiled to Intermediate Language.  The IL is Just-In-Time compiled to the target architecture (usually x86, but can be any architecture to which the CLR has been ported) the first time the assembly is loaded/run.

Answer (score 0):

Oh by the way once you are on the subject of learning about assemblies in .Net :

- [Assemblies could span multiple files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/grantri/archive/2004/07/07/175745.aspx)
- and [you could build code to MSIL without it being in an assembly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/02/12/371683.aspx) (But at some point you will need to link it in an assembly to be able to use it)